# Request/get response as json including mutiple objects for geolocation API

Tags: json, google-maps, google-geolocation

I'm trying to send a request as a json including **multiple objects** and get the response back in same way for geolocation API.
But when I request json including multiple object, **the response includes only an object for the first object in json requested**.
I know the geolocation API is not included in Google Maps API for Work, but I don't know where I have to discuss about this.
What should I do for getting a json as a response including multiple objects

Comment: Can you provide the section of code that is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Would love to see the request listed in this question, but I don't think the API was designed for that. According to the [api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/#body)

The request body should be passed as a single object:

```
{
  "homeMobileCountryCode": 310,
  "homeMobileNetworkCode": 410,
  "radioType": "gsm",
  "carrier": "Vodafone",
  "cellTowers": [
   // See the Cell Tower Objects section below.
   ],
   "wifiAccessPoints": [
    // See the WiFi Access Point Objects section below.
   ]
}
```

Though multiple cell towers or access points can be specified.

I believe you will need to make multiple requests if you have multiple objects to pass.